# US International (AltGr dead keys) layout on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

everyone. On Linux there is a layout called US International (AltGr dead keys), which converts the right Alt key into an AltGr key. AltGr+a gives á, AltGr-Shift-a gives Á, AltGr-m gives µ, and AltGr-' followed by another key puts the acute accent on whatever you type next, and so on.

This is pretty much my favorite keyboard layout, because it's really convenient both for programming and for typing foreign-language text (both of which I do quite a bit) but unfortunately I can't find an option for this layout. The "US International - PC" layout uses ', ", and ` and so on as dead keys directly, which doesn't work because as mentioned I program a lot.

I found a layout called "US International w/o Dead Keys" [here](http://www.twam.info/hardware/us-international-on-os-x), but when I load it into Lion the keyboard simply stops working. Does anyone know anywhere else I could find this layout, or how I could customize one for myself?

Answer (score 4):

The standard U.S. layout has a few dead key states under <kbd>⌥</kbd>:

[image]

<kbd>`</kbd> isn't a dead key in U.S. Extended:

[image]

If you want to leave the left <kbd>⌥</kbd> free for other functions, you can create a custom `.keylayout` with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele).

Answer (score 2):

Here we go: https://github.com/xv0x7c0/osx-us-altgr-intl this is mostly the same you can find on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

In Lion, when you hold a key, a popup menu shows up with the alphabet you're holding with the accents.  If you want to have quick access with them, then there are some of the common ones where you can easily just hold Option then the alphabet (Though not all of the accents are available through that way).

Answer (score 1):

Use this app to make a custom layout:

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Answer (score 0):

MacOS has many user-friendly keyboard special characters. For example, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> -> `≤`

If this is not good enough for your needs, try out [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/343928)