# Is it possible to use US English keyboard layout with dead keys in Mavericks similar to those from Windows and Linux?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I read [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/30471/61618) that *"The standard U.S. layout has a few dead key stated under <kbd>⌥</kbd>"*. Does that mean that pressing Alt+that key would make that key act as a dead one?

I am looking for a layout that uses as dead keys the symbols that look like accents before the letters that one wants accented, like the "US-International" in Win7 and "English-US, with dead keys" in Ubuntu-Linux. In these layouts, the keys for ` , ' , ^ , " are dead. After them, Space key brings the character as such, while something like **e** will bring è, é, ê, ë respectively.

Are there such keyboard layouts for Mac? (I am very new to the system.)

(I am not looking for answers like "use this app and create your own layouts".)

Comment: Where do you get your definition of what dead keys "really" are?

Comment: @DanielLawson - i have tried to edit the question to make it more suitable. please suggest edits instead of down-voting. i expect that a lot of visitors here are new mac users like me and a question like this may be useful. my confusion came from the fact that in the layouts i use with dead keys outside mac the dead key gives precisely nothing, while in mac, as i see after receiving the TomG's answer below, the dead-key symbol is **visible into the document** until  replaced by the accented letter. because i was seeing a letter typed with that key i thought that the key wasnt "really" dead :)

Comment: Great. I couldn't tell if you had a real question or if you were ranting that Apple wasn't doing dead keys "right" according to your definition of dead keys. Now I see you're actually looking for something in particular, and not just saying "they're doing it wrong." +1

Comment: @DanielLawson - on the contrary, they're doing it better !! -- indeed, the way things are in mac is helpful because one sees what "dead key" one has just pressed. but i was not expecting that key to still be called "dead"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your new question is the US International PC layout provided by Apple.

Comment: that is indeed the answer for me! i was not used with the fact that the dead key DOES display a character until the letter to be accented is pressed! so, i was convinced that it was not the "dead" key i was looking for.  for example, i was expecting  the key **"** to give nothing and then just to get the accented letter **ë** with the stroke of **e**, while in fact the dead letter gives the **"** symbol until **e** is typed

Comment: @cipricus That is why the character produced by pressing the dead key is displayed with a yellow background. Pressing space or moving the cursor will insert exactly that character.

Answer (score 1):

They don't normally produce absolutely nothing.  You will usually see the accent mark in yellow when you press the dead key.  Here is a list of standard accent dead keys

http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codemac.html#accent

That is:

For each accent, a certain **different** key has to be used along with the Option (Alt) key , **before** the letter that we want accented:

For example, for the accents with the letter O:

Acute   accent (ó Ó)           Option+E, o
Circumflex  (ô Ô)   Option+I, o
Grave   (ò Ò)   Option+`, o
Tilde   (õ Õ)   Option+N, o     Only works with "n,o,a"
Umlaut  (ö Ö)   Option+U, o

Example 1: To input the letter ó, hold down the Option key, then the E key. Release both keys then type lowercase o.

Example 2: To input the letter Ó, hold down the Option key, then the E key. Release both keys then type capital O.

Comment: This answer was helpful to me.